# Do XSLT 3 accumulators in non-streaming mode provide a performance benefit compared to XPath expressions?

Tags: xslt, saxon

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
<persons>
  <person age="14" name="John"/>
  <person age="23" name="Rob"/>
  ...
</persons>
```

I want to find the youngest person in the list.

It seems I could do this with an ordinary XPath expression (something like `//person[@age=min(//person/@age)]`). In XSLT 3 I could also write an accumulator like this:

```
<xsl:accumulator name="acc" initial-value="()">
   <xsl:accumulator-rule match="person" select="if(@age &lt; $value/@age) then . else $value"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

And then call `accumulator-after('acc')` when I need it.

In a non-streaming context, is there a benefit in using one over the other? I would think that, at the least, using an accumulator would save me from writing potentially inefficient XPath expressions. Or would a sophisticated XPath processor (in my case, Saxon) optimize the query to the equivalent of using an accumulator and is it therefore not important how I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The cases where an accumulator might be faster than a regular XPath expression are where you need to compute some value for many nodes in a document (for example, a section number, or a year-to-date total), and the value for node N can be conveniently expressed as a function of the value for an earlier node. xsl:number is a classic case. But you could also achieve this using XSLT 3.0 memo functions.

If your XPath expression uses the preceding axis, then that's a signal that accumulators might help.

Answer (score 0):

The most "creative" use of an accumulator without streaming I could come up with so far is when trying to use the XPath 3.1 function `random-number-generator`, it is kind of tricky to use the `?next()` function if you want to process it for certain nodes in the tree, an accumulator makes that easy, for example:

```
  <xsl:accumulator name="random-number" as="map(*)" initial-value="random-number-generator(current-dateTime())">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" select="$value?next()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
```

and use it as in e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:comment select="accumulator-before('random-number')?number"/>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
```

That kind of processing where you don't need a single value but need to compute a value for certain matched nodes in a tree where the value of the next node depends on the previous one is the kind of use an accumulator without streaming where a single XPath expressions might be harder or you would need to use a tunnel parameter in XSLT 2 or 3 if not using an accumulator.